# Remove this warning error on XCode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How to remove the below warning error on Xcode 6,

Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to ‘BOOL’ (aka ‘Signed char’) from ‘NSArray *__strong’

Here below my code is,

```
 NSMutableArray *objectsToShareArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [objectsToShareArr addObject:@"xyz"];
        [objectsToShareArr addObject:@"abc"];

        UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];

        UIActivity *activity                    =   [[UIActivity alloc] init];

        NSArray *applicationActivities          = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:activity, nil];

        UIActivityViewController *controller    = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShareArr applicationActivities:applicationActivities];

        NSArray *excludedActivities = @[ UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,

                                        UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,

                                        UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypeMail,

                                        UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,

                                        UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,

                                        UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,

                                        UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo];

        controller.isAccessibilityElement = excludedActivities;
         [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If anyone have solution for this I really appreciate to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
controller.isAccessibilityElement = excludedActivities;
```

You should do this instead for adding share options:

```
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:excludedActivities applicationActivities:nil];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. If I remove this line then how to show the social share options on iOS8 ?